# Is it possible to mute and unmute sound from <object> and <embed>

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, audio, embed

So I have an `<object>` and `<embed>` (which is the fallback) loaded into a html file (index.html)
like so:

```
<object id="glitch" 
 data="skull/Glitch" 
 width="100%" height="100%" 
 style="overflow:hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow-y: hidden;">

<embed id="glitch-embed" 
 src="skull/Glitch" 
 width="100%" height="100%"> 
</embed>
Error: Embedded data could not be displayed.
</object>
```

Inside the object is an `<audio>` tag that plays when the glitch happens I want to know if I can mute and unmute the audio tag inside the object and embed via a button in the index.html file how would one go about doing this?

Here is my button in the index.html it also controls other sounds in the index

Html:

```
<a href="#" class="mute-button MuteOff link">
    <i id="mute-icon" class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
    </a>
```

js

```
  $('.mute-button').on('click tap touch', function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if( $this.hasClass("MuteOn") ) {
    audio1.volume=1.0;
    audio2.volume=1.0;
    audio3.volume=1.0;
    audio4.volume=1.0;
    audio5.volume=1.0;

    $this.removeClass("MuteOn").addClass("MuteOff");
     $('#mute-icon').removeClass("fa fa-volume-off").addClass("fa fa-volume-up");


        } else {

    audio1.volume=0.0;
    audio2.volume=0.0;
    audio3.volume=0.0;
    audio4.volume=0.0;
    audio5.volume=0.0;

    $this.removeClass("MuteOff").addClass("MuteOn");
          $('#mute-icon').removeClass("fa fa-volume-up").addClass("fa fa-volume-off");
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance
site I'm working on with this problem: https://ui-unicorn.co.uk

Comment: Please make a minimal demo (MVCE) for us to  test

Comment: Read about the [mcve] here if you aren't sure what that entails.